# How do you fetch a global constant using key-value coding in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, key-value-observing, nslocalizedstring

I am writing a method that will give localized names of CNPostalAddress elements. The localization keys I am attempting to retrieve are global constants.

```
/// Get the localised name of a CNPostalAddress element
///
/// - Parameter field: CNPostalAddress element name (Street, SubLocality, City, SubAdministrativeArea, State, PostalCode, Country, ISOCountryCode)
/// - Returns: localized name of the address field


func localizedAddressFieldName(for field: String) -> String? {
    let keyPathKey = "CNPostalAddress\(field)Key"

    if let localizationKey = value(forKey: keyPathKey) as? String {
        return CNPostalAddress.localizedString(forKey: localizationKey)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

However, the application crashes when getting the the `localizationKey` with the following log:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[<MyProject.MyViewController 0x7fd83d81c8b0>
>   valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant
>   for the key CNPostalAddressStreetKey.'

`CNPostalAddressStreetKey` is a valid key, as shown in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cnpostaladdress/postal_address_property_keys), but is a Global constant.

**Solution**

```
extension CNPostalAddress {
    class func localizedAddressFieldName(for field: String) -> String? {
        let localizationKey = field.decapitalizingFirstLetter()
        return CNPostalAddress.localizedString(forKey: localizationKey)
    }
}

extension String {
    func decapitalizingFirstLetter() -> String {
        let firstLetterLowercase = String(prefix(1)).lowercased()
        return firstLetterLowercase + String(dropFirst())
    }
}
```

Comment: what returns `value(forKey: keyPathKey)`?

Comment: `value(forKey: keyPathKey)` is a method defined in `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol, you are calling that method in your viewController that is why is crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you may have to use those variables instead:

```
print("\(CNPostalAddress.localizedString(forKey: "subLocality"))")
print("\(CNPostalAddress.localizedString(forKey: "street"))")
```

so instead of

```
let keyPathKey = "CNPostalAddress\(field)Key"
```

you should use

```
let keyPathKey = "\(field)"
```

it's case sensitive, so you might have to make some adjustments.

see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cnpostaladdress)

Answer (score 0):

First `value(forKey: keyPathKey)` is a method defined in `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol, you are calling that method in your viewController that is why is crashing to avoid the crash you have to implement that method in your `ViewController`

```
override func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {

}
```

**but anyway I think you don't need call this method in first instance**

```
func localizedAddressFieldName(for field: String) -> String? {
    let localizationKey = "CNPostalAddress\(field)Key"

    return CNPostalAddress.localizedString(forKey: localizationKey)
}
```

If your key is not defined in `CNPostalAddress` the result will be an empty string

Comment: @NSGoat did my answer help you? I had accepted your edition

Comment: I had initially tried your solution but no localizations were returned as `CNPostalAddressStreetKey` maps to "street", and not "CNPostalAddressStreetKey". I ended up simply decapitalising the first letter of the field name and passing that as the key. Thanks for your input.